# Data validation with EitherT-s inside for-comp

Tags: scala, validation, design-patterns, functional-programming, for-comprehension

Consider a simplified version of the problem that I'm trying to solve. Here's my current implementation.

```
case class Foo()

def addFoo(json: String): EitherT[Future, Exception, Long] = {
  def parse(json: String): EitherT[Future, Exception, Foo] = ???

  def validate(foo: Foo): EitherT[Future, Exception, Foo] = ???

  def save(foo: Foo): EitherT[Future, Exception, Long] = ???

  for {
    foo <- parse(json)
    _ <- validate(foo)
    id <- save(foo)
  } yield id
}
```

This doesn't feel right because, although `validate` returns an `EitherT` of `Exception` or `Foo`, it just performs the validation and returns either an exception or an unchanged `foo` value. So, we are never interested in the right part of the `Either` and never use it. Is there any approach that corresponds better to the "validation" semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about right value you can just use `Unit` instead of `Foo`, like:

```
def validate(foo: Foo): EitherT[Future, Exception, Unit] = ???
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change type signature of `validate` to add more type safety:

`def validate(foo: Foo): EitherT[Future, Exception, ValidFoo]`

where `ValidFoo` looks like that:

```
object ValidFoo {
  def believeMeItsValid(raw: Foo): ValidFoo = new ValidFoo(raw)
}

class ValidFoo private (val foo: Foo)
```

and `save` would accept only validated input:

`def save(foo: ValidFoo): EitherT[Future, Exception, Long]`

This would force you to validate input before saving it and help against **boolean blindness**.